# PHP (Laravel) Convert string stored in db to array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a string stored in a database field as 
["Quia sed magnam optio sapiente et ipsum.", "Necessitatibus voluptatem aut praesentium et tenetur unde impedit iusto.", "Ea blanditiis sunt ab."]
and when I retrieve that value from the DB, I need to convert that it an array, I tried unserealize.

edit **The answer that helped me**

```
investments = json_decode(["Quia sed magnam optio sapiente et ipsum.",
 "Necessitatibus voluptatem aut praesentium et tenetur unde 
impedit iusto.", "Ea blanditiis sunt ab."], true);
```

Comment: Did you hear mutators?

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of accessors and mutators, specifically when looking for my solution to this. So I am using code in an accessor to get the db value as a json array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

returnArray= json_decode('["Quia sed magnam optio sapiente et ipsum.", "Necessitatibus voluptatem aut praesentium et tenetur unde impedit iusto.", "Ea blanditiis sunt ab."]', true);

To get pure array do not forget to use true in function, othwerwise will return json object

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and a nice answer to start off with! For additional clarity in your answers, or questions, you can [format them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) with markdown, and you can also edit your answer whenever.

Comment: Thanks, I tried json_decode but without the true, this works great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to use: `explode($string,",")`, giving you an indexed array of strings from your main string.

Comment: this gives me array:1 [▼
  0 => ","
]

Comment: This solution is assuming you have decoded the json beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

for saving a array as string in database and after get it as array you must in model define a $casts like this :

```
    protected $casts = [
      'column_name' => 'array'
    ];
```

based on variable $casts, you can change the type of a field in the Larval model.
other examples for $casts:

*when you want get a field as boolean :*

```
protected $casts = [
  'is_published' => 'boolean'
];
```

*when you want get a field as specific format data :*

```
protected $casts = [
  'published_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

in this way, data have become the preferred format before getting the data